# Certificate chain verifier error in sun solaris Server certificate rejected by ChainVerifier

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, solaris, tibco

I am invoking java method from TIBCO BW where I am passing the certificate path. Java method loading the public certificate and invokes https thirdparty URL. In my windows all working fine but in sun solaris I am getting below error. Any possible solution for this. Below my solaris version. I downloaded public certificate from URL and get it converted to p12 format whic I am using.

SunOS abcd1 5.10 Generic_150400-30 sun4v sparc sun4v

The method [com.abcd.abcde.eps.impl.abcdservice.doGetabcdStatus] raised exception [com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException].  com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while silently connecting: org.w3c.www.protocol.http.HttpException: iaik.security.ssl.SSLException: Server certificate rejected by ChainVerifier

raised exception [com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException].  com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while silently connecting: org.w3c.www.protocol.http.HttpException: iaik.security.ssl.SSLException: Server certificate rejected by ChainVerifier

Comment: You probably need to post the code you're using to validate the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

"rejected by ChainVerifier"  usually means that you are missing one or more Root / intermediate certificates.

Check the certificate that you are passing to the java method and ensure that the list of (root) certificates you have on the solaris box is the same as you have on windows.
Likely you need to download the whole chain of root and intermediate certificates and make them available as trusted certs.